# XPath or XQuery to exclude article sections which only contains lists

Tags: xpath, xquery

I am trying to extract the sections of an article (Introduction, History, Overview....). I look for an XPath to select all the sections which begin with a heading and contain some paragraphs. If they only contain a list, they should be discarded.

For example :

```
<h2>Intro</h2>
<p> It has paragraph and should be extracted </p>
.....
<h2>References </h2>
<ul>...It has just list and should be discarded </ul>
<h2>...</h2>
....
```

If XPath is not possible, an XQuery could also work.
I tried the following XQuery

```
for $x in doc("test.xq")//h2
return
   <section>{$x/following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h2[1] is $x]}</section>
```

It selects the sections as I want, but I couldn't impose the condition (not only `ul`) to it.

Comment: To extract fragment of xml you need 2 reference s. In your xml all h2 are equivalent. I can't suppouse you the answer, Variant of extracting you may look there  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629183/xpath-for-selecting-a-section-of-an-article/30630155#30630155

Comment: @splash58, Thank you for your previous answers, I included them into the question, but I don't know how to impose a further condition over the extracted content (as it is in question)!

Comment: and returns boolean always

Comment: you need `//*[preceding::$x and following::$y]` ie take all having x before and y ahead

Comment: @splash58 I replaced your suggestion after `return` now it gives the Error `Expecting node test after preceding axis`

Comment: i don't know Xquery. maybe it is illegal syntax. It is just logic of query

Comment: $x/following::*[following::$y] - test so

Answer (score 2):

You mention in another question that this is in BaseX, which supports the XQuery 3.0 `group by` mechanism, so how about this:

```
for $x in doc("test.xq")//h2/following-sibling::*[not(self::h2)]
group by $hId := generate-id($x/preceding-sibling::h2[1])
return
  if ($x[not(self::ul)]) then
    <section>{($x/preceding-sibling::h2[1], $x)}</section>
  else ()
```

Here I'm first finding all the non-h2 elements that we want to gather together (there may be a more efficient way to do this depending on the structure of your XML), then the `group by` means that on each "iteration" the `$x` variable will be the sequence of non-h2 elements between one h2 and the next.  The `if` condition then checks whether there is at least one element in this group that is not a `ul`.

Comment: I have tested it. It gave a result with an element <ul> ...<ul>

Comment: @Win.ubuntu it will give you `ul` elements as part of a group that also includes non-ul elements, the requirement was to exclude groups that contain _only_ `ul` elements and nothing else.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes it works (except if the `ul` is nested in some `div`s), but it repeats the heading before any element (for example paragraphs) of a section

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, in this case there is no condition to create xpath.

You should scan the tree. When h2 found, begin to collect fragment. If you meet p before h2 mark the fragment to save, else drop it and begin saving from that h2.

It can be done both using dom structure or with text searching of `<h` and `<p`.

Comment: I modified my question, is there an XQuery for this problem?