# Xpath select nodes between two nodes in scrapy 0.24.5

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
<h3>Q1</h3>  
<p><p>text1</p></p><a name="1"> </a>  
<p>...</p>  
...  
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<h3>Q2</h3>  
<p>text2</p><a name="2"> </a>  
<p>...</p>  
...  
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
<h3>Q3</h3>  
<p>text3</p>
<p>...</p>  
...  
<ul><li>...</li></ul>
```

Above is my html, and I want to grab the text of individual h3 and text of the nodes that follow it till the next h3. In other words, if I were to put them in a dictionary, the result would look like:

```
{Q1:text1, Q2:text2, Q3:text3}
```

I tried first selecting all the h3 tags, and then loop through the list of h3 tags. For each h3 tag, I tried to select all the nodes before the next h3 tag. Here is my code:

```
>>> h3_tags = response.xpath(".//h3")   
>>> for h3_tag in h3_tags:    
>>>     texts = h3_tag.xpath("./following-sibling::node()[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=1]/descendant-or-self::text()").extract()
```

But this only extract the p text for after the first h3 tag (besides that it also include the text of the second h3 tag), and I got nothing for the rest of the h3 tags.

if I use:

```
>>> h3_tags = response.xpath(".//h3")   
>>> for h3_tag in h3_tags:    
>>>     texts = h3_tag.xpath("./following-sibling::node()[preceding-sibling::h3]/descendant-or-self::text()").extract()
```

I got redundant texts from previous p for the second and third h3.

I'm using this in Scrapy 0.24.5, and this is my first day. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629183/xpath-for-selecting-a-section-of-an-article/30630155#30630155

Comment: Hi splash58, thanks for the link. I edited my code accordingly: `texts = h3_tag.xpath("./following-sibling::*[preceding-sibling::h3[1][contains(.,title)] and not (name()='h3')]/descendant-or-self::text()").extract()` but for the first and second h3, I got redundant contents belonging to next h3. If I add `(count(preceding-sibling::h3)=1)` to the condition, I only got content for the first h3 tag, and not the ones after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the `count(preceding-sibling...)` technique, with some help from `enumerate()`

```
>>> for cnt, h3 in enumerate(selector.xpath('.//h3'), start=1):
...     print h3.xpath('./following-sibling::node()[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=%d]' % cnt).extract()
... 
[u'  \n', u'<p></p>', u'<p>text1</p>', u'<a name="1"> </a>', u'  \n', u'<h3>Q2</h3>']
[u'  \n', u'<p>text2</p>', u'<a name="2"> </a>', u'  \n', u'<h3>Q3</h3>']
[u'  \n', u'<p>text3</p>']
>>> 
>>> for cnt, h3 in enumerate(selector.xpath('.//h3'), start=1):
...     print h3.xpath('./following-sibling::node()[count(preceding-sibling::h3)=%d]/descendant-or-self::text()' % cnt).extract()
... 
[u'  \n', u'text1', u' ', u'  \n', u'Q2']
[u'  \n', u'text2', u' ', u'  \n', u'Q3']
[u'  \n', u'text3']
>>>
```

Note that `<p><p>text1</p></p>` did not play well with lxml, creating 2 sibling `p`s and not a `p` in `p`

Comment: I thought `count(preceding-sibling::h3)=1` would eliminate those h3-following siblings that are not immediate siblings of the current h3. Any idea why that didn't work?

Comment: For the 2nd h3 for example, the following-siblings have at least 2 h3 that came before. Remember siblings are at the same level in the tree. You just need to count preceding elements that make your "boundaries"